# Invoke Resumable Upload URI in Google Drive from Client

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api

I have written a Node app that generates the Drive Resumable Upload URL on the server side. I do this to not expose the access token to the client.

```js
const url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable';
  const { headers } = await axios.post(url,{name: "File Name"}, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
      'X-Upload-Content-Type': type,
      'X-Upload-Content-Length': size,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    },
  });
```

I then pass this upload URL to the client and use it to upload the file to Google Drive in Chunks. However it returns the cors error. The error doesn't happen if I upload chunks from the server using the same upload URI.

Is it that the resumable upload URI should be invoked from the same host where it was originally requested from? Is it possible to bypass this restriction since I do not want to expose the token to the client.

Comment: Which CORS error are you getting? What is the full response? What type of application is this set up as in the Google Cloud Platform console?

Comment: The error is Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin. See screenshots at https://i.imgur.com/pKm51et.png and https://i.imgur.com/bltcMsp.png

Comment: I understand - yes, the origin of the host that makes the request must match the origin of the host that completes the upload of the file. This is a privacy feature and cannot be bypassed. Check out [this article](https://web.dev/same-site-same-origin/#same-origin-and-cross-origin) for explanation on what this means and why